# Using two different databases in Flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently using couchdb as my backend for my flask application.

I currently have some huge master files that I am not able to put into couch (CouchDB throws an OS errorwhen I build a view function for these lookup files... thats a whole different bag that I want to get to at a later point).

These lookup files do not have any relation to the datasets in the couchdb dataset and I was wondering if I can shift only these lookup files to either a mySQL or a PostgreSQL database.

Is it possible for one flask app to handle multiple databases (I would use couchdb Manager and Flask-SQLAlchemy here for instance).

Regards,
Galeej

Comment: Yes it is, [docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/binds/)

Comment: Those are two different sql databases right?  Does it support 1 sql and 1 couchdb database?

Comment: Then, I think I've misunderstood your question and flask-sqlalchemy's binds are not your solution. I'd advise you to try yourself by creating small sandbox application using sqlalchemy and couchdb simultaneously, because ATM I see no problems with using both db's in Flask as they are pluggable.

Comment: how do I execute raw sql using bind? `db.engine.execute`